# Installing LuaMongo on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, lua

I have researched and viewed the post to install luamongo- http://groups.google.com/group/luamongo/browse_thread/thread/1eaa56974614dc90/c91c842e241aa4de#c91c842e241aa4de

But the installation will not work. I already have mongodb-10gen version 2.0.3 and lua5.1 version 5.1.4.10 installed.

How do I download luamongo from https://github.com/moai/luamongo and install it and get it working as an import statement in a lua script to be able to write to a mongo db? Any suggestions would be helpful, nothing I have tried so far or read has been able to help. If more information is needed I will post it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this script from a friend of mine which should be helpful:

```
# Download mongodb and driver
wget http://downloads.mongodb.org/cxx-driver/mongodb-linux-x86_64-v2.0-latest.tgz
wget http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz

# Extract each
tar xvzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz
tar xvzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-v2.0-latest.tgz

# Add mongo bin to PATH
export PATH=$PATH:~/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.0.2/bin

# Grab dev tools and dependencies (May need to run apt-get update to download all)
sudo apt-get -y install tcsh scons libpcre++-dev libboost-dev libreadline-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-date-time-dev gcc g++ git lua5.1-dev make

# Grab latest luamongo (will need to add your github ssh key)
git clone git@github.com:moai/luamongo

# Compile mongo driver
cd mongo-cxx-driver-v2.0
sudo scons install

# Install where lua can load it
sudo cp libmongoclient.* /usr/lib
```

Comment: I am unable to do git clone to get luamongo, can you wget with the http address provided on github?